# Make a redirect_to without route name using Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I'm using engines on my Rails application. This essentially means that the application and its engine can have identically named routes and they will not clash.

So, I have two types of routes, inside the engine and outside  routes and they are called differently:

**With the name of route:**

Inside the engine:

```
redirect_to  main_app.books_show_path
```

Outside the engine

```
redirect_to books_show_path
```

But I have a php application who calls to rails routes sending the controller and the action of the route that it wants to go.
So, I haven't got the route name.
If the route it's outsite the engine I haven't got problems because this works:

```
redirect_to (controller: books,action: show)
```

But when I want to go to inside the engine route I don't know how to do it. I need something like this:

```
redirect_to (controller: books,action: show,path: main_app)
```

$rake routes | grep books

```
books GET  /books(.:format) MiEngine/books#index    
Routes for MiEngine::Engine:    
books GET  /books(.:format) MiEngine/books#index
```

Comment: Does your engine have `isolated_namespace`?

Comment: Yes, isolate_namespace MiEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **url_for** with these params:

- If you have got the name of the route:

  ```
  redirect_to url_for([nameOfYourEngine, nameOfYourRoute])

  redirect_to url_for([main_app, 'books_show'])
  ```
- If you haven't got the name of the route:

  ```
  redirect_to url_for([nameOfYourEngine,nameController, nameMethod])

  redirect_to url_for([main_app,'books','show'])
  ```